# JMeter - / replaced with %2F when posting in subsequent HTTP request

Tags: asp.net, regex, authentication, jmeter

Application: ASP.NET

Value captured in Regex post processor:

```
__VIEWSTATE:  /wEPDwULLTEwMjgyMTI3ODAPZBYCAgEPZBYCAgEPDxYCHgRUZXh0ZWRkZAX+cy5B/46umWN01upyRg2q//kD
```

Value posted in HTTP request:

```
__VIEWSTATE:  %2FwEPDwULLTEwMjgyMTI3ODAPZBYCAgEPZBYCAgEPDxYCHgRUZXh0ZWRkZAX+cy5B%2F46umWN01upyRg2q%2F%2FkD
```

Problem: `/` is replaced with `%2F` when posting.

Response: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Appreciate any help in sorting out this issue...

Comment: Have you tried [HTMLDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to proceed:

1. Uncheck "Encode?" box for __VIEWSTATE parameter of [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) - it will be sent as is.
2. Use [__urldecode()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) JMeter Function
3. Use [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) with the following code:

   ```
   import java.net.URLDecoder;
   vars.put("VIEWSTATE", URLDecoder.decode(vars.get("VIEWSTATE"), "UTF-8"));
   ```

The code above assumes that variable holding your viewstate is called VIEWSTATE

Comment: The problem is: Post processor(RegEx) for previous page captures the value as "/wEPDwULLTEwMjgyMTI3ODAPZBYCAgEPZBYCAgEPDxYCHgRUZXh0ZWRkZAX+cy5B/46umWN01upyRg2q//kD" However when sending it in the next http request it is converted as "%2FwEPDwULLTEwMjgyMTI3ODAPZBYCAgEPZBYCAgEPDxYCHgRUZXh0ZWRkZAX+cy5B%2F46umWN01upyRg2q%2F%2FkD"