# How to stop encoding my variable when sending request?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using jmeter to perform a performance test on my ASP.Net web form based application. Using a regular expression extractor I am extracting value which has / and = characters on it. 
When sending that extracted value with the next request it encodes and replace / and = . This makes my script fails.

[image]

Even though I un-tick "Encode" checkbox it keeps happening.

Any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678634/jmeter-replaced-with-2f-when-posting-in-subsequent-http-request 
But still those answers are not working for me