# JMeter 5.3 - Incorrect decoding of the URL during recording

Tags: url, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to create a load test with JMeter for a 1-page website for a customer. For this I use the default template of JMeter "recording" ([Test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7btv.jpg)).I noticed that I can login to the website with JMeter without problems, but it reads the URL's incorrectly.

The actual URL should look like this: **https://www.example.com/tool**

However, he changes this URL as follows: **http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ftool**

Obviously JMeter encodes something wrong. I see the error of the wrong decoding in the logfile of Apache Tomcat and in the „Request“ > „Raw“ ([position of "Raw"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI8YB.jpg)). Everywhere else like in the .jmx file URL is correct.

Unfortunately I'm absolutely new to JMeter and generally a layman when it comes to computer science. Since I didn't find an implementation that I can understand, I hope someone can help me with this.
I found this old post ([JMeter - / replaced with %2F when posting in subsequent HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678634/jmeter-replaced-with-2f-when-posting-in-subsequent-http-request)) which did not help me. I work with the latest version 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture requests which are send by JMeter and the real browser. If there is a mismatch - it's a JMeter problem which needs to be reported via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html). You can just replace encoded URL with the non-encoded one using JMeter's "Search" function:

[image: https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html]

However if the requests are the same then JMeter correctly does [URL-encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

Also be aware of the alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/) which doesn't require extra configuration in terms of proxies and certificates